# Date is coming as millis after decompression - Different behaviour on different machine

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, json-deserialization, jackson-databind

I have a table with a column of **Date** type. Let's say table column is:

REPORTING_CONVERSION_DATE     NOT NULL DATE

DAO class (which implements **Serializable**) has the corresponding field defined as:

```
@Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
@Column(name = "REPORTING_CONVERSION_DATE")
private Date reportingConversionDate;
```

I extract the record from database, use **com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper** to get json string representation of the object, compress the json and store this in Cosmos DB in Azure. During the reverse leg, I get the record from Cosmos DB, decompress it, use ObjectMapper to read the java object back.

I found that on one machine(the code is running on springboot embedded Tomcat with jar as the packaging type) I see this:

**reportingConversionDate : 1424483105000**

while on other machine (the code is running on managed Tomcat with war as the packaging type) I see

**reportingConversionDate : 2015-02-21T01:45:05.000+0000**

Why is this different behaviour?

Comment: Could you please clarify where (which conversion) you are getting the different conversion. Also post the code for the DAO, if it is possible.

Comment: do you use the same code in both running app ? check the Date import !
if `java.util.date` or `java.sql.date`

Comment: @Ironluca Do you mean which mapper I am using?

Comment: @SpringerF it is the same code running in both app.